# Unable to see SharePoint search service under services on server

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Background: I have two server 2016 farm. one if Webfrontend with DIstribution cache and the other server role is Application with Search.
I have installed search service application on App server using PowerShell commands. PowerShell is successfull.

But when I go back to "Service on Server" page, I don't see SharePoint server search service at all. I don't see anything related to search there.

Also when I select Search service application  under service application dashboard, search administration throws an error "remote server 503". but all the remaining components looks active.

I am scratching my head about these two issues. I tried all the recommended steps from internet and no luck

Tried IISreset
stopped and started timer server
ran enable-sptimer job
re-ran SharePoint configuration wizard

Important one: I don't see Searchadmin.svc and serachservice.svc under ISS websites. Somehow they are missing

Answer (score 0):

See: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230596/cannot-get-sharepoint-2016-search-working

And: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/552566-sharepoint-foundation-2013-search-service?page=1&source=homepage-feed#entry-3635667

Here are the troubleshooting steps mentioned above:

- If you have multiple servers in SharePoint farm, make sure all servers have the same date and time settings.
- Go to IIS->Connections -> Sites -> YourSite->Click Authentication > Enable anonymous authentication.
- Remove the SharePoint server from the SharePoint farm and re-add.
- Go to services on computer-> right click on the “SharePoint Server Search 16” service-> select properties-> log on tab -> re-enter the user name & password of domain user->restart the “SharePoint Server Search 16” service.
- Re-run the SharePoint 2016 products configuration wizard and check the result.
- Repair the SharePoint 2016 product. Go to control panel->right click “Microsoft SharePoint server 2016”->click Repair.